# What is the exact axis value of a grid tick location?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, grid

I cannot figure out a precise value of a tick location because I do not know how the scale works. For example, in the following scenario:

```
> dput(df_partial_2)
structure(list(v = 8:400, Tv_partial = c(7.98105946849764, 8.73878705524418, 
9.47352664242238, 10.1859798998468, 10.8768274522901, 11.546729501371, 
12.1963264293038, 12.826239385031, 13.4370708532459, 14.0294052067967, 
14.6038092429507, 15.1608327039841, 15.7010087825473, 16.2248546122473, 
16.7328717438707, 17.2255466076639, 17.7033509620725, 18.1667423293303, 
18.6161644182794, 19.0520475347892, 19.4748089801349, 19.8848534376828, 
20.2825733482202, 20.6683492742624, 21.0425502536523, 21.405534142766, 
21.7576479496252, 22.0992281572083, 22.4306010372483, 22.7520829547891, 
23.0639806637737, 23.3665915939217, 23.6602041291518, 23.9450978777947, 
24.2215439348345, 24.489805136414, 24.7501363068249, 25.0027844982076, 
25.2479892231676, 25.4859826805202, 25.7169899743615, 25.941229326661, 
26.1589122835664, 26.3702439156033, 26.5754230119487, 26.7746422689521, 
26.9680884730723, 27.1559426783938, 27.3383803788816, 27.515571675528, 
27.6876814385425, 27.8548694647289, 28.0172906301918, 28.1750950385095, 
28.3284281645058, 28.4774309937505, 28.6222401579151, 28.7629880661037, 
28.8998030322791, 29.0328093988977, 29.1621276568663, 29.2878745619276, 
29.4101632475811, 29.5291033346404, 29.6448010375253, 29.7573592673884, 
29.8668777321649, 29.9734530336404, 30.0771787616219, 30.1781455852996, 
30.2764413418811, 30.3721511225791, 30.4653573560312, 30.5561398892264, 
30.6445760660137, 30.7307408032637, 30.8147066647521, 30.8965439328325, 
30.9763206779655, 31.0541028261659, 31.1299542244299, 31.2039367042032, 
31.2761101429469, 31.3465325238588, 31.4152599938029, 31.4823469195027, 
31.5478459420476, 31.611808029764, 31.6742825294991, 31.7353172163643, 
31.7949583419839, 31.8532506812946, 31.9102375779375, 31.9659609882845, 
32.0204615241418, 32.0737784941661, 32.1259499440361, 32.1770126954122, 
32.227002383724, 32.2759534948179, 32.3238994005003, 32.3708723930087, 
32.4169037184423, 32.4620236091842, 32.5062613153437, 32.5496451352497, 
32.5922024450215, 32.6339597272468, 32.674942598791, 32.715175837766, 
32.7546834096823, 32.7934884928088, 32.8316135027644, 32.8690801163648, 
32.9059092947446, 32.9421213057798, 32.9777357458282, 33.0127715608099, 
33.0472470666478, 33.0811799690861, 33.1145873829068, 33.14748585056, 
33.1798913602291, 33.2118193633436, 33.2432847915594, 33.2743020732209, 
33.3048851493212, 33.3350474889736, 33.3648021044129, 33.3941615655357, 
33.4231380139978, 33.4517431768788, 33.4799883799295, 33.5078845604127, 
33.5354422795497, 33.5626717345866, 33.5895827704883, 33.6161848912738, 
33.642487271004, 33.6684987644302, 33.6942279173145, 33.7196829764334, 
33.7448718992726, 33.7698023634215, 33.7944817756786, 33.8189172808753, 
33.843115770427, 33.8670838906179, 33.8908280506314, 33.9143544303296, 
33.937668987792, 33.9607774666199, 33.9836854030141, 34.0063981326306, 
34.0289207972252, 34.0512583510889, 34.0734155672827, 34.0953970436786, 
34.1172072088102, 34.138850327541, 34.1603305065546, 34.1816516996727, 
34.2028177130061, 34.2238322099433, 34.2446987159822, 34.2654206234098, 
34.2860011958333, 34.3064435725688, 34.3267507728909, 34.346925700147, 
34.3669711457419, 34.3868897929958, 34.4066842208781, 34.4263569076246, 
34.4459102342371, 34.4653464878726, 34.484667865123, 34.5038764751908, 
34.5229743429622, 34.541963411981, 34.5608455473279, 34.5796225384059, 
34.5982961016364, 34.6168678830676, 34.6353394608986, 34.6537123479216, 
34.6719879938843, 34.6901677877762, 34.708253060039, 34.7262450847056, 
34.7441450814691, 34.761954217683, 34.7796736102968, 34.7973043277266, 
34.8148473916649, 34.8323037788297, 34.8496744226562, 34.8669602149322, 
34.8841620073785, 34.901280613177, 34.9183168084477, 34.9352713336757, 
34.9521448950907, 34.9689381660001, 34.9856517880761, 35.0022863726003, 
35.0188425016658, 35.0353207293377, 35.0517215827748, 35.0680455633125, 
35.0842931475085, 35.1004647881526, 35.1165609152417, 35.1325819369209, 
35.1485282403922, 35.1644001927908, 35.1801981420321, 35.1959224176277, 
35.2115733314733, 35.2271511786088, 35.2426562379515, 35.2580887730034, 
35.2734490325325, 35.288737251231, 35.3039536503486, 35.3190984383043, 
35.3341718112745, 35.3491739537616, 35.3641050391398, 35.3789652301832, 
35.3937546795724, 35.4084735303836, 35.4231219165597, 35.437699963363, 
35.4522077878117, 35.4666454990999, 35.4810131990013, 35.4953109822585, 
35.5095389369564, 35.5236971448821, 35.537785681871, 35.5518046181384, 
35.5657540186003, 35.5796339431791, 35.5934444470997, 35.6071855811722, 
35.6208573920644, 35.6344599225624, 35.6479932118224, 35.66145729561, 
35.6748522065322, 35.6881779742576, 35.7014346257297, 35.7146221853696, 
35.7277406752709, 35.7407901153869, 35.7537705237088, 35.7666819164374, 
35.7795243081463, 35.792297711939, 35.8050021395982, 35.81763760173, 
35.8302041078994, 35.8427016667617, 35.8551302861874, 35.8674899733808, 
35.8797807349937, 35.8920025772338, 35.9041555059675, 35.9162395268184, 
35.9282546452606, 35.9402008667078, 35.9520781965976, 35.963886640472, 
35.9756262040536, 35.9872968933178, 35.9988987145614, 36.0104316744679, 
36.0218957801686, 36.0332910393006, 36.0446174600623, 36.0558750512647, 
36.0670638223806, 36.0781837835905, 36.0892349458256, 36.1002173208092, 
36.111130921094, 36.1219757600986, 36.1327518521402, 36.1434592124663, 
36.1540978572838, 36.1646678037854, 36.1751690701755, 36.1856016756927, 
36.1959656406317, 36.2062609863626, 36.2164877353493, 36.2266459111657, 
36.2367355385108, 36.2467566432224, 36.2567092522888, 36.2665933938604, 
36.2764090972585, 36.2861563929844, 36.2958353127264, 36.3054458893661, 
36.3149881569836, 36.3244621508616, 36.3338679074887, 36.3432054645623, 
36.352474860989, 36.3616761368869, 36.3708093335841, 36.3798744936191, 
36.3888716607389, 36.3978008798968, 36.4066621972502, 36.4154556601571, 
36.4241813171723, 36.4328392180434, 36.4414294137055, 36.4499519562765, 
36.4584068990513, 36.4667942964954, 36.4751142042391, 36.4833666790704, 
36.4915517789274, 36.499669562892, 36.507720091181, 36.5157034251392, 
36.5236196272302, 36.5314687610289, 36.5392508912119, 36.5469660835497, 
36.5546144048966, 36.5621959231825, 36.5697107074028, 36.5771588276094, 
36.584540354901, 36.5918553614133, 36.5991039203094, 36.6062861057698, 
36.6134019929824, 36.620451658133, 36.6274351783945, 36.6343526319172, 
36.6412040978187, 36.6479896561739, 36.6547093880043, 36.6613633752684, 
36.667951700851, 36.6744744485537, 36.6809317030839, 36.6873235500453, 
36.6936500759276, 36.6999113680962, 36.7061075147822, 36.7122386050729, 
36.7183047289007, 36.7243059770343, 36.7302424410682, 36.7361142134128, 
36.7419213872849, 36.7476640566979, 36.7533423164519, 36.7589562621244, 
36.7645059900605, 36.7699915973636, 36.7754131818859, 36.7807708422192, 
36.7860646776854, 36.7912947883274, 36.7964612749003, 36.8015642388619, 
36.8066037823638, 36.811580008243, 36.8164930200124, 36.8213429218528, 
36.8261298186035, 36.8308538157543, 36.8355150194369, 36.8401135364163, 
36.8446494740827, 36.849122940443, 36.853534044113, 36.8578828943088, 
36.8621696008394, 36.8663942740982, 36.8705570250556, 36.8746579652508, 
36.8786972067844, 36.8826748623109, 36.8865910450307), upper = c(8.03359225925823, 
8.80857834632081, 9.5612639540498, 10.2924319542762, 11.0027615088121, 
11.6928792116129, 12.3633783233509, 13.0148273942128, 13.6477746695034, 
14.2627505985141, 14.8602694075212, 15.4408301755264, 16.0049176292822, 
16.5530027709442, 17.085543401016, 17.6029845727229, 18.1057589993884, 
18.5942874281687, 19.0689789887631, 19.5302315225719, 19.9784318961527, 
20.4139563015338, 20.8371705451927, 21.2484303270819, 21.6480815106972, 
22.0364603848133, 22.4138939176628, 22.7807000039433, 23.1371877048629, 
23.483657481973, 23.8204014245163, 24.1477034710795, 24.4658396252724, 
24.7750781659481, 25.0756798521194, 25.3678981224866, 25.6519792899843, 
25.9281627314614, 26.1966810723811, 26.4577603670466, 26.7116202742093, 
26.9584742281375, 27.1985296055078, 27.4319878880867, 27.6590448211454, 
27.8798905679742, 28.0947098605409, 28.303682146198, 28.5069817307874, 
28.7047779179796, 28.8972351451356, 29.0845131157104, 29.2667669283157, 
29.4441472022976, 29.6168002003046, 29.7848679474905, 29.9484883479501, 
30.1077952978449, 30.2629187955558, 30.4139850494996, 30.5611165825133, 
30.7044323337553, 30.8440477582857, 30.9800749232191, 31.1126226023811, 
31.2417963677869, 31.3676986784984, 31.4904289682926, 31.610083729402, 
31.7267565955176, 31.8405384216734, 31.9515173620422, 32.0597789462855, 
32.1654061533981, 32.2684794831148, 32.3690770267303, 32.4672745344442, 
32.5631454822052, 32.6567611359263, 32.7481906140996, 32.837500949199, 
32.924757146882, 33.0100222434937, 33.0933573629117, 33.1748217705806, 
33.2544729270661, 33.3323665397096, 33.4085566127212, 33.4830954965083, 
33.5560339350466, 33.6274211119235, 33.6973046960334, 33.7657308845263, 
33.8327444461067, 33.8983887619512, 33.9627058662137, 34.0257364851272, 
34.0875200750857, 34.1480948594313, 34.2074978650149, 34.2657649565552, 
34.3229308710607, 34.3790292508966, 34.4340926756696, 34.4881526941562, 
34.5412398538176, 34.5933837311924, 34.6446129601967, 34.6949552603321, 
34.7444374635548, 34.7930855410287, 34.8409246284613, 34.8879790518782, 
34.9342723507123, 34.9798273022007, 35.0246659442585, 35.0688095978648, 
35.1122788884366, 35.155093766912, 35.1972735304098, 35.2388368426575, 
35.2798017523627, 35.3201857126241, 35.3600055990019, 35.3992777278467, 
35.4380178729083, 35.4762412824328, 35.5139626950424, 35.5511963569724, 
35.5879560358473, 35.6242550362788, 35.660106214586, 35.6955219932856, 
35.7305143739968, 35.7650949511975, 35.799274924944, 35.8330651144483, 
35.8664759690332, 35.8995175805539, 35.9321996949078, 35.9645317237364, 
35.9965227545901, 36.0281815616323, 36.0595166157857, 36.0905360958059, 
36.1212478965051, 36.1516596385052, 36.181778677794, 36.2116121145547, 
36.2411668014046, 36.2704493514818, 36.2994661468907, 36.3282233466523, 
36.3567268944537, 36.3849825252517, 36.4129957724961, 36.4407719758422, 
36.4683162877621, 36.4956336789202, 36.5227289452774, 36.5496067144771, 
36.576271451485, 36.6027274639768, 36.6289789077896, 36.6550297930879, 
36.680883989219, 36.7065452293272, 36.7320171152315, 36.7573031227545, 
36.7824066060878, 36.8073308017407, 36.8320788325874, 36.8566537133383, 
36.8810583533731, 36.9052955606898, 36.9293680454236, 36.9532784242442, 
36.9770292236016, 37.0006228824751, 37.0240617555395, 37.0473481170782, 
37.0704841638112, 37.0934720175169, 37.1163137271682, 37.1390112728497, 
37.1615665679841, 37.1839814617295, 37.2062577405082, 37.2283971318262, 
37.2504013057289, 37.2722718773406, 37.2940104076643, 37.3156184070184, 
37.3370973368792, 37.358448611312, 37.3796735974135, 37.4007736195177, 
37.421749959301, 37.4426038580381, 37.4633365164149, 37.4839490983855, 
37.5044427309976, 37.5248185065204, 37.5450774822177, 37.5652206837748, 
37.5852491045726, 37.6051637081801, 37.6249654278839, 37.6446551690956, 
37.6642338095978, 37.6837022011351, 37.703061169198, 37.7223115139911, 
37.741454012788, 37.7604894191547, 37.7794184641224, 37.7982418559697, 
37.8169602831027, 37.8355744125794, 37.8540848919306, 37.872492348051, 
37.8907973901634, 37.9090006082374, 37.9271025750828, 37.9451038444129, 
37.9630049547664, 37.9808064261408, 37.9985087637145, 38.0161124549964, 
38.0336179734073, 38.0510257756606, 38.0683363048293, 38.0855499870236, 
38.1026672357657, 38.1196884486032, 38.1366140107796, 38.1534442910924, 
38.1701796470854, 38.1868204204564, 38.2033669415581, 38.2198195249735, 
38.2361784746205, 38.2524440791669, 38.2686166160704, 38.2846963481008, 
38.3006835261952, 38.3165783890704, 38.3323811614011, 38.3480920564971, 
38.3637112736246, 38.3792390009633, 38.3946754130837, 38.4100206728362, 
38.4252749293159, 38.4404383204303, 38.4555109705401, 38.4704929925236, 
38.4853844850299, 38.5001855362607, 38.5148962198147, 38.5295165982694, 
38.5440467200941, 38.5584866218206, 38.5728363271117, 38.5870958472277, 
38.6012651793252, 38.6153443093285, 38.629333208128, 38.6432318360453, 
38.6570401376072, 38.670758046363, 38.684385481021, 38.6979223479721, 
38.7113685398104, 38.7247239349367, 38.7379884000929, 38.7511617857575, 
38.7642439311501, 38.7772346590262, 38.7901337808324, 38.8029410919209, 
38.8156563751269, 38.8282793970572, 38.8408099121518, 38.8532476581625, 
38.865592361234, 38.877843729249, 38.8900014587311, 38.9020652284304, 
38.9140347046908, 38.9259095360921, 38.9376893586157, 38.9493737905985, 
38.9609624369689, 38.9724548850766, 38.9838507088844, 38.9951494636204, 
39.0063506910751, 39.0174539163475, 39.0284586462466, 39.0393643745615, 
39.05017057558, 39.0608767095718, 39.0714822171156, 39.0819865251073, 
39.0923890401102, 39.1026891543754, 39.1128862395446, 39.1229796535302, 
39.1329687326205, 39.1428527984061, 39.1526311517042, 39.1623030775114, 
39.1718678404131, 39.1813246883321, 39.1906728477217, 39.199911528907, 
39.2090399205426, 39.2180571938361, 39.2269624992342, 39.2357549667289, 
39.2444337083123, 39.2529978130782, 39.2614463525713, 39.2697783738833, 
39.2779929070221, 39.28608895693, 39.2940655099318, 39.3019215280794, 
39.3096559535962, 39.3172677037989, 39.3247556757764, 39.3321187408153, 
39.3393557498253, 39.3464655268798, 39.3534468740051, 39.3602985675711, 
39.3670193603561, 39.3736079784372, 39.3800631235048, 39.3863834698938, 
39.3925676666143, 39.3986143351158, 39.4045220686833, 39.4102894343671, 
39.4159149688177, 39.4213971814072, 39.4267345508319, 39.4319255263988, 
39.4369685255292, 39.4418619360456, 39.4466041125389, 39.451193377326, 
39.4556280194739, 39.4599062940958, 39.4640264210152, 39.4679865851237, 
39.471784934444, 39.4754195799749, 39.4788885944803, 39.4821900115524, 
39.4853218247947, 39.4882819872413, 39.4910684089741, 39.4936789576808, 
39.4961114568045, 39.4983636822029, 39.5004333662267, 39.5023181900198, 
39.5040157873157, 39.5055237408116, 39.5068395794376, 39.5079607785615, 
39.5088847588695, 39.5096088825276, 39.5101304540473, 39.5104467142662, 
39.5105548434037, 39.5104519552204, 39.510135096546, 39.5096012441735, 
39.5088473033011, 39.5078701034415, 39.5066663979697, 39.5052328591409, 
39.5035660760377, 39.5016625518232, 39.4995186993156, 39.4971308389636, 
39.494495193108, 39.4916078852114, 39.4884649309263, 39.4850622390609
), lower = c(7.92852667773705, 8.66899576416754, 9.38578933079495, 
10.0795278454174, 10.7508933957681, 11.4005797911291, 12.0292745352567, 
12.6376513758492, 13.2263670369884, 13.7960598150793, 14.3473490783802, 
14.8808352324417, 15.3970999358125, 15.8967064535504, 16.3802000867254, 
16.8481086426048, 17.3009429247567, 17.7391972304919, 18.1633498477956, 
18.5738635470064, 18.9711860641172, 19.3557505738318, 19.7279761512478, 
20.088268221443, 20.4370189966073, 20.7746079007188, 21.1014019815875, 
21.4177563104733, 21.7240143696337, 22.0205084276052, 22.3075599030311, 
22.5854797167639, 22.8545686330312, 23.1151175896412, 23.3674080175496, 
23.6117121503413, 23.8482933236656, 24.0774062649539, 24.2992973739542, 
24.5142049939938, 24.7223596745136, 24.9239844251844, 25.119294961625, 
25.3084999431199, 25.491801202752, 25.66939396993, 25.8414670856036, 
26.0082032105896, 26.1697790269758, 26.3263654330763, 26.4781277319494, 
26.6252258137474, 26.767814332068, 26.9060428747215, 27.040056128707, 
27.1699940400104, 27.2959919678801, 27.4181808343625, 27.5366872690024, 
27.6516337482958, 27.7631387312192, 27.8713167900999, 27.9762787368766, 
28.0781317460617, 28.1769794726695, 28.2729221669899, 28.3660567858314, 
28.4564770989883, 28.5442737938418, 28.6295345750816, 28.7123442620887, 
28.792784883116, 28.8709357657768, 28.9468736250546, 29.0206726489125, 
29.0924045797971, 29.16213879506, 29.2299423834597, 29.2958802200047, 
29.3600150382321, 29.4224074996608, 29.4831162615243, 29.5421980424001, 
29.5997076848059, 29.6556982170252, 29.7102209119393, 29.7633253443856, 
29.8150594468069, 29.8654695624899, 29.9146004976819, 29.9624955720443, 
30.0091966665558, 30.0547442713486, 30.0991775304623, 30.1425342863324, 
30.1848511221186, 30.226163402945, 30.2665053157387, 30.3059099080167, 
30.3444091246209, 30.3820338444454, 30.4188139149567, 30.454778185988, 
30.4899545426987, 30.5243699365313, 30.5580504166818, 30.5910211588507, 
30.623306494297, 30.6549299372498, 30.6859142119773, 30.7162812783359, 
30.7460523571562, 30.7752479536507, 30.8038878820173, 30.8319912872885, 
30.8595766673012, 30.8866618937915, 30.9132642331833, 30.9394003663836, 
30.9650864077624, 30.9903379231561, 31.0151699487574, 31.0395970078341, 
31.0636331276854, 31.087291855272, 31.1105862735336, 31.1335290162095, 
31.1561322829049, 31.1784078518534, 31.200367095224, 31.2220209917168, 
31.2433801391715, 31.2644547665734, 31.2852547468285, 31.305789607902, 
31.3260685442293, 31.3461004265282, 31.3658938135144, 31.3854569614542, 
31.4047978339526, 31.4239241108925, 31.4428431982768, 31.461562236913, 
31.4800881110573, 31.4984274555513, 31.5165866652456, 31.5345719023488, 
31.5523891034418, 31.570043986708, 31.5875420592547, 31.6048886241021, 
31.6220887863492, 31.6391474593759, 31.6560693708075, 31.6728590691987, 
31.6895209296817, 31.7060591587233, 31.7224777995951, 31.7387807387001, 
31.7549717098046, 31.771054298632, 31.7870319478604, 31.8029079620354, 
31.818685512097, 31.8343676388765, 31.8499572576007, 31.8654571623394, 
31.8808700299061, 31.8961984230273, 31.9114447942062, 31.9266114897432, 
31.9417007534042, 31.9567147284179, 31.9716554618761, 31.9865249077845, 
32.0013249303215, 32.0160573060017, 32.03072372678, 32.0453258034493, 
32.0598650684224, 32.0743429775776, 32.0887609130007, 32.103120185756, 
32.117422038967, 32.1316676489476, 32.145858127859, 32.1599945260391, 
32.1740778350442, 32.1881089882518, 32.2020888636823, 32.2160182855976, 
32.2298980277018, 32.2437288135753, 32.257511318574, 32.2712461720178, 
32.2849339602458, 32.2985752257947, 32.3121704705634, 32.3257201567189, 
32.339224709939, 32.3526845185099, 32.3660999363538, 32.3794712836611, 
32.3927988497824, 32.4060828923773, 32.4193236406279, 32.4325212951514, 
32.4456760307915, 32.458787996454, 32.4718573170272, 32.484884093882, 
32.4978684071072, 32.5108103164923, 32.5237098610539, 32.5365670616296, 
32.5493819214592, 32.5621544280945, 32.5748845521528, 32.5875722503671, 
32.600217465287, 32.612820127852, 32.6253801558434, 32.6378974568276, 
32.6503719273791, 32.6628034562844, 32.6751919218421, 32.6875371964082, 
32.6998391438086, 32.7120976232832, 32.7243124869592, 32.7364835834842, 
32.7486107559379, 32.7606938460958, 32.7727326909604, 32.7847271270201, 
32.7966769874202, 32.8085821069102, 32.8204423174316, 32.8322574534563, 
32.8440273482061, 32.8557518387685, 32.8674307616563, 32.8790639580336, 
32.8906512702879, 32.9021925460985, 32.9136876361492, 32.9251363950583, 
32.9365386837237, 32.9478943671477, 32.9592033175954, 32.970465412101, 
32.9816805354316, 32.9928485786233, 33.0039694414233, 33.0150430301115, 
33.0260692602336, 33.037048054894, 33.0479793478448, 33.0588630800318, 
33.0696992040632, 33.080487680927, 33.0912284833659, 33.1019215939782, 
33.1125670064116, 33.1231647251472, 33.1337147674364, 33.1442171606589, 
33.1546719463397, 33.1650791758897, 33.1754389160296, 33.1857512441582, 
33.1960162523946, 33.2062340452232, 33.2164047411336, 33.2265284731705, 
33.2366053865426, 33.2466356433653, 33.2566194177858, 33.266556901311, 
33.2764482977688, 33.2862938282037, 33.2960937274025, 33.3058482477041, 
33.3155576550292, 33.3252222334887, 33.3348422803843, 33.344418112939, 
33.353950061466, 33.36343847585, 33.3728837202419, 33.3822861784755, 
33.3916462489552, 33.4009643497524, 33.4102409144165, 33.4194763961868, 
33.4286712638407, 33.4378260070782, 33.4469411312562, 33.4560171606742, 
33.4650546401982, 33.4740541300161, 33.4830162121407, 33.4919414849452, 
33.5008305688532, 33.5096841003456, 33.518502738622, 33.5272871595919, 
33.5360380621786, 33.5447561614472, 33.553442196504, 33.562096923572, 
33.5707211220696, 33.5793155896568, 33.5878811468251, 33.5964186331457, 
33.6049289120718, 33.6134128655934, 33.6218713997717, 33.6303054405085, 
33.6387159368526, 33.6471038606822, 33.6554702042407, 33.6638159850243, 
33.6721422404196, 33.680450034595, 33.6887404511186, 33.6970146009249, 
33.7052736158521, 33.7135186542826, 33.7217508966821, 33.7299715506615, 
33.7381818462813, 33.7463830416085, 33.754576417274, 33.7627632829134, 
33.7709449723599, 33.7791228472345, 33.7872982948628, 33.7954727313648, 
33.8036475993218, 33.811824370725, 33.8200045449252, 33.828189650849, 
33.8363812475827, 33.8445809224218, 33.8527902950166, 33.8610110142303, 
33.8692447615159, 33.8774932496098, 33.8857582250076, 33.8940414656565, 
33.9023447845684, 33.9106700288418, 33.9190190806168, 33.9273938577594, 
33.9357963151771, 33.9442284444407, 33.9526922757018, 33.9611898778265, 
33.9697233595884, 33.978294870584, 33.9869066020308, 33.9955607873286, 
34.0042597044217, 34.0130056752231, 34.0218010674443, 34.030648297918, 
34.0395498285005, 34.048508173752, 34.0575258971226, 34.0666056145592, 
34.0757499972172, 34.0849617712391, 34.0942437188543, 34.1035986822, 
34.1130295624387, 34.1225393257587, 34.1321310003018, 34.1418076819866, 
34.1515725349625, 34.1614287947003, 34.1713797695316, 34.1814288447239, 
34.1915794829163, 34.201835229085, 34.2121997125799, 34.2226766498556, 
34.2332698488808, 34.2439832111475, 34.2548207373935, 34.2657865283575, 
34.2768847936956, 34.2881198510005)), row.names = 8:400, class = "data.frame")
```

```
ggplot(df_partial_2, aes(log(log(v)))) + theme_bw() + xlab("v") + ylab(bquote(lnT[v])) +  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~floor(exp(exp(.))), sec.axis=sec_axis(~., name = "ln ln v")) +                   
  geom_line(aes(y=log(upper)), linetype="dashed") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=log(Tv_partial))) +
  geom_line(aes(y=log(lower)), linetype="dashed")
library("grid")
grid.lines(x = unit(c(0, 0), "npc"), y = unit(c(0.05, 0.1), "npc")) # line
grid.lines(x = unit(c(1, 1), "npc"), y = unit(c(0.05, 0.1), "npc")) # line
grid.text("<- unit(c(0, 0)) is here", 0.01, .075, just=c("left", "bottom"))
grid.text("unit(c(1, 1)) is here ->", 0.84, .075, just=c("left", "bottom"))
grid.lines(x = unit(c(0.4, 0.4), "npc"), y = unit(c(0.05, 0.1), "npc")) # line
grid.text("What is the value of v at this tick?", .3, .11,just=c("left", "bottom"))
```

[image]

As shown in the plot, the function `grid` put the ticks at a location based on a scaled percentage of the entire plot panel (not the axis). In other words, `unit(c(0.4, 0.4))` on `x` means the tick is at the 40%-60% separation of the entire plot panel, not of the axis. As a consequence, I don't know what is the actual value on the axis for the tick location.

Is there a way to figure out what is the axis value of the tick location?
Or, if I want a small tick to be add onto v = 18 in the plot, is there a way to do it?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use plotly `library(plotly)`, assign you plot to p `p <- ggplot(df_p......` then plot `ggplotly(p)` and you'll get tool tips. With your code, the line `ylab(bquote(lnT[v]))` and the two grid lines will need commenting out for plotly to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no consistent answer. Per the `grid::unit()` [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/unit), "all drawing occurs relative to a viewport." Which means the location will change based on the viewport aspect ratio (and maybe other factors too). For instance, in your example, the tick is about 2/3 between 11 and 27. But if my viewport has a lower aspect ratio, the same code puts the tick about halfway between 11 and 27:

[image]

If you're trying to add an extra tick mark, specify `breaks` including the extra tick within `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
ggplot(df_partial_2, aes(log(log(v)))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=log(upper)), linetype="dashed") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=log(Tv_partial))) +
  geom_line(aes(y=log(lower)), linetype="dashed") +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("v") + 
  ylab(bquote(lnT[v])) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = ~floor(exp(exp(.))),
    breaks = c(.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8),
    sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks = c(.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8), name = "ln ln v")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My original intent was to add a tick at a particular location. It seems that the grid does not help. How can I add a tick based on the value of v to my plot? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to add an extra tick without specifying all other ticks, but after searching on stack overflow and reading your answer, it appears that your answer is the only and the best way of doing it by far. Thanks again.

Comment: You could specify the breaks as `breaks = ~ c(scales::extended_breaks()(.x), 1.1)`. This will use the default breaks plus whatever value(s) you add (1.1 in this case). Although this doesn't work inside `sec_axis()`, not sure why.